# Can we offer prayer at a different location than the original place where we intended to?

Tags: temple

I have prayed to offer pooja at Kukke Subrayamaniya temple (Karnataka) but due to some reason I could not go there and offer my prayers. I want to know if I can offer the same prayer at Katte Subrayamaniya temple in Bangalore instead?

Comment: yes you can do it in any place for now, but when you got time you should go to kukke subrayamaniya   temple and do the pooja.

Comment: @Raman At least how it works for the Venkateshwara temple in Tirupati is that if you've promised to do something there, you're allowed to do it in the temples of any of the "elder brothers", i.e. Venkateshwara temples like Upillaiappan that are even older than the Tirupati statue.  The same thing may apply to Kartikeya, so perhaps you should go to a Kartikeya temple where the idol is older than the idol of the Kukke Subramaniya temple.  I would recommend asking the priests of the Katte Subramaniya temple of pujas promised in other temples can legitimately be done there.

Comment: It is always recommended to offer prayers at the same temple that you made a promise to visit. Each place has its own power.